# How can I share JSON data with one scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is my Angular controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    var promise = $http.get("url1")
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.files = [response.data]
            return $http.get('url2', {
                params: {
                    id: response.data[0].Id
                }
            })
        })
    .then(function (response2) {
        console.log(response2);
        $scope.files = response2.data;
        return response2.data;
    })
}])
```

my HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="category">
    <a href="{{file.Url}}"><strong>{{file.Name}}</strong></a>
    <ul ng-if="(files | filter:{ParentId : file.Id}).length > 0">
        <li ng-repeat="file in files | filter: {ParentId : file.Id" ng-include="'category'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
<ul class="btn-highlight plus">
    <li ng-repeat="file in files | filter: {ParentId : 0}" ng-include="'category'"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

ParentId = response.data.Id in my Angular controller.

My question is how can I include response and response2 in my scope called $scope.files at the same time and call my response.data.Id in my html code(ParentId)?

Comment: The ParentId variable on your UI should be called $scope.ParentId on your controller code. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I tried that but the matter is with ng-if = files and when i do that $scope.ParentId isn't $scope.files, i don't know if you understand me.

Comment: filter params are backwards. To filter matching `file.Id` would be `filter:{Id:ParentId}` where ParentId is  scope model variable. Not sure what you are trying to do. Broken code is not a good substitute for proper explanation

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestion charliefl.

Comment: Do you want to set response & response2 whole data set into scope? Put the response & response2 result set and your are wanting data format.

Comment: Is `$scope.files =  $scope.files.concat(response2.data);` what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried response & response Bilas, but it didn't work, but it has to be with then promise because of my JSON.

Comment: Yes Bilas, i want it!!!

Comment: I hope your comment wasn't a sarcasm Bilas.

Comment: Bergi, it says to me $scope is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code to this.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
var promise = $http.get("url1")
    .then(function (response) {
    var response1 = [];
        console.log(response);
        response1 = response.data;
        $scope.files = [response.data]
        return $http.get('url2', {
            params: {
                id: response.data[0].Id
            }
        })
    })
.then(function (response2) {
    console.log(response2);
    var response2 = [];
    response2 = response2.data;
    var allResponse = [];
    allResponse = response2.data.concat(response1);
    $scope.files = allResponse;
    return response2.data;
})}])
```

Comment: your response.data is undefinied because your data key is not exist in response object .

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed your code a little bit because it had few mistakes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the scope outside of the promise .. but anyway why in god's name are you using nested promises instead of the $q service ? That's callbacksHell , and it sucks as code ..
Use the $q , that's its basic use case ..

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.files = [];
    var promise = $http.get("url1")
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return $http.get('url2', {
                params: {
                    id: response.data[0].Id
                }
            })
        })
    .then(function (response2) {
        console.log(response2);
        $scope.files = response2.data;
        return response2.data;
    })
}])
```

Comment: I'm using nested promise because response2 is inside of response.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my point of view, well i'm already edited my post.